# Get length of shift (difference between two times)

Tags: php, datetime

I'm working on an app and am trying to calculate the length of time a shift would take. When I input 09:00 pm and 6:00 am, the shift time gets set to 15:00 instead of 08:00.
The sample code I've used is here:

```
$shiftfrom = new DateTime($shiftfrom);
$shiftto = new DateTime($shiftto);
$hours = $shiftfrom->diff($shiftto);
$hours = $hours->h.":".$hours->i; //how long a shift is
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: 09:00 pm and 6:00 am-> 9 hours. Am i right?

Comment: `$date1 = new DateTime('2006-04-12 21:00:00');`
`$date2 = new DateTime('2006-04-13 06:00:00');`

`// The diff-methods returns a new DateInterval-object...`
`$diff = $date2->diff($date1);`

`// Call the format method on the DateInterval-object`
`echo $diff->format('%h hours');`

Please check your `$shiftfrom` and `$shiftto` have proper datetime.

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes. That's the idea

Comment: @DhananjayKyada There are no dates in the $shiftfrom and $shiftto variables. They are sent from html `<input type="time">` element to the php script.

Comment: @FrankenCode make sure `$shiftto` is set on next day.. otherwise you get the right result

Comment: @FrankenCode  date is also needed, otherwise how you will come to know that PM belongs to yesterday and AM belongs to today?

Comment: @AlivetoDie and DhananjayKyada I guess I could use a dummy date. I'll try that out. Update: I tried to set $shiftfrom to today and $shiftfrom to tomorrow. But that causes a new problem. Even if the time is from 8:00 am to 5:00 pm, the shift length calculates it as 33 hours instead of 9 hours

Comment: @FrankenCode  at the time of form submission you have to get corresponding date for  both times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$shiftfrom = "2019-06-24 09:00 PM";
$shiftto = "2019-06-25 06:00 AM";

$datetime1 = new DateTime($shiftfrom);
$datetime2 = new DateTime($shiftto);

$diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

$hours = $diff->h;
$hours = $hours + ($diff->days*24);
$time = $diff->i;


echo $hours.":".$time;
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you. However, I don't get why $diff->days*24 is required. Since $diff->days will always return 0 in my case.